# Moving from acts_as_versioned to paper_trail gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, versioning, paper-trail-gem

In our Rails app, we used **act_as_versioned** gem to versioning our models. One table for each versioned model.

Currently, we're upgrading our technological stack and we need to use another gem (due to compatibility issues with **Rails 5**). **Paper Trail** gem seems promising but can we use the current data in our versioned model tables?

We look at the documentation but we didn't find any suggestion about this.

Comment: I presume you're talking about [this gem](https://github.com/mjsommer/acts_as_versioned)? I've never used this library before (it's very old and little-known!), but my instinct would be to try creating a new model and "re-playing history" from the old one.

Comment: Or maybe you're using [the original](https://github.com/technoweenie/acts_as_versioned)??? I've just realised there are tonnes of forks of this thing - presumably because the original project was abandoned 6 years ago :)

Comment: I'm currently using the original gem. All the existing forks are not compatible with Rails 5. That's why I need to use something else. I'll try to adapt the existing tables to work with paper_trail for now. Thanks for the comments @TomLord :).